# MOSFET simulation model

Tags: mosfet

I am trying to model a synchronous buck converter, for which I need to choose mosfet models for simulations. I am seeing that it has various parameters out of which length and width is affecting the simulation results.

What should be the values for length and width in MOSFET parameters for simualtions?

How does it affect \$R_{DSon} \$?

Answer (score 0):

It won't really help you but: It depends on the MOSFET you want to simulate: different MOSFETs can have different parameters. Pick the datasheet of the MOSFET you plan to use for your circuit.

The RDSon is proportional to the length and inversely proportional to the width: it varies as L/W.

Here you can find the equation: https://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/ex012.htm